# Why would the implicitly generated constructor (et al.) be more efficient than a user-defined (trivial) one?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, constructor

I read this [article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=514&WT.rss_f=Guide&WT.rss_a=C%20%200x%20Features%20That%20I%20Like,%20Part%20I%20&WT.rss_ev=a) from D. Kalev this morning about the new c++11 feature "defaulted and deleted functions", and can't understand the part about performance, namely:

> the manual definition of a special member function (even if it's trivial) is usually less efficient than an implicitly-defined one.

By googling to find an answer, I found another [article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=15) of the same author:

> the synthesized constructor and copy constructor enable the implementation to create code that's more efficient than user-written code, because it can apply optimizations that aren't always possible otherwise.

There is no explication, but I read time to time similar claims.

But how is it that writing:

```
class C { C() = default; };
```

can be more efficient than

```
class C { C(){} };
```

? I though a compiler would be smart enough to detect such situation and optimize that. In other words how is it easier for the compiler to optimize when it sees `=default` instead of `{}` (void body function)?

Edit: the question was edited to add the "c++11" tag, but this question remains in c++03 context: just replace `class C {C()=default;};` by `class C {};`, so not really a c++11 specific question.

Comment: Good question. I would also think that any compiler not optimizing this is defective. Let’s see if someone can give a good reason why that’s not possible.

Comment: Try with a C++1x compiler to generate the assembly. This will answer your question definitely. I doubt there is any difference, since as you say, the compiler is smart enough. Comments like the one you quoted are bad, in my opinion, because it makes C++ developers to think too much about performance. 99% of the time there are other qualities to worry about before even considering silly micro performance-optimizations.

Comment: @Daniel: thanks, but I know nothing about assembly, and I'm not at all interested in gaining micro-performance... But I'm interested to know *why* there would be any gain, be it micro.

Comment: are you sure they are similar, meaning, the second one is an inline definition but I am unsure about the first.

Answer (score 7):

You ask, how is it that

```
class C { C() = default; };
```

can be more efficient than

```
class C { C(){} };
```

Well, both constructors do nothing, so it's meaningless to talk about efficiency for that example.

But more generally, in e.g. a copy constructor one can imagine that copying one POD item at a time will not be recognized as optimizable by simple optimizer, whereas with automatic generation it might just do a `memcpy`. Who knows. It's a Quality of Implementation issue, and I can easily imagine also the *opposite*.

So, measure, if it matters.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I totally agree, but Kalev gives almost the same example (a virtual default destructor in fact), and he says (quoted in the post): "even if it is trivial", hence my question. But I will never measure that, I wanted to understand the true reasons, not given by the author.

Comment: It's not true that both cases do nothing, they both initialize all the class's members using their default constructors (if they are not primitives)

Comment: @Motti: in the concrete example above, they do nothing. In that case it's meaningless to talk about efficiency. In a modified example, one with data members, they will generally have *different* effect. And so in that case, although efficiency can be talked about, it's not comparable. I didn't see any point in discussing that hypothetical case. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 7):

It makes no sense whatsoever to talk about "manual definition of a special member function (even if it's trivial)", because user-provided special member functions are, by definition, non-trivial.  This non-triviality comes into play when using type traits, and also POD-ness, and many optimizations are only possible with trivial or POD types.

A better restatement of the same quote would be:

*The defaulted special member functions enable **libraries** to detect that calls to these functions may be omitted entirely.*

From section 12.1 `[class.ctor]`

> A default constructor is *trivial* if it
>   is neither user-provided nor deleted
>   and if:
>
> - its class has no virtual
>     functions (10.3) and no virtual base
>     classes (10.1), and
> - no non-static
>     data member of its class has a
>     brace-or-equal-initializer, and
> - all
>     the direct base classes of its class
>     have trivial default constructors, and
> - for all the non-static data members
>     of its class that are of class type
>     (or array thereof), each such class
>     has a trivial default constructor.
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is
>   *non-trivial*.

From section 12.8 `[class.copy]`:

> A copy/move constructor for class X is
>   *trivial* if it is neither user-provided
>   nor deleted and if
>
> - class X has no
>     virtual functions (10.3) and no
>     virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - the constructor selected to copy/move
>     each direct base class subobject is
>     trivial, and
> - for each non-static
>     data member of X that is of class type
>     (or array thereof), the constructor
>     selected to copy/move that member is
>     trivial;
>
> otherwise the copy/move
>   constructor is *non-trivial*.

From section 9, `[class]`:

> A *trivially copyable* class is a class
>   that:
>
> - has no non-trivial copy
>     constructors (12.8),
> - has no
>     non-trivial move constructors (12.8),
> - has no non-trivial copy assignment
>     operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
> - has no
>     non-trivial move assignment operators
>     (13.5.3, 12.8), and
> - has a trivial
>     destructor (12.4).
>
> A *trivial class* is a class that has a
>   trivial default constructor (12.1) and
>   is trivially copyable. [ Note:  in
>   particular, a trivially copyable or
>   trivial class does not have virtual
>   functions or virtual base classes. —
>   end note ]

Answer (score 2):

Take performance claims "with a grain of salt".

I've heard a high-rated MIT professor make a claim like that for his favorite thing, and the only reason nobody asked him "why" was because he was a high-rated MIT professor.

Such constructors and destructors might have other advantages, but claims about performance (outside of big-O) are seldom even meaningful except in highly contrived circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I can't see it either.

Among other things, I can see why one should use

```
class C { C() = default; };
```

that seems to me the same as

```
class C { };
```

Or, if other constructors are provided, as:

```
class C { 
    C() {}
    // other constructors.
};
```

I fail to see the **real problem** the author is writing about here.

Comment: I do like Daniel Lidström's comment under the question here. I think it points at what unreal problem the author is writing about.

Comment: The first two ARE the same, the default constructor is defaulted, explicitly or implicitly makes no difference.  "If other constructors are provided" is **exactly** the reasoning for the new `= default` syntax, since it allows creating a *trivially-copyable* class with user-defined conversions.  The constructor with an empty body is sufficient to make the class *non-trivially copyable*.

Comment: @Ben ok, but it seems to me that the point of the article was the ability, by the compiler, to output a more optimized binary with the `= default` syntax.

Comment: I suggest you read my answer for a more detailed look.  There's a problem with the article insofar as the author isn't using the standard definition of *trivial* (and I don't mean commonly accepted definition, I mean the ISO C++ standard explicitly states what *trivial* means in the context of C++ classes, constructors, and destructors).  And the result is that the difference between a defaulted constructor and an empty user-defined one is not important to the compiler, but to library code that uses type traits.  For some libraries it could be a very big difference indeed.